# Searching simpler proof for convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

It is known that if $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $x_n \to x$ then $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$. As an example, this can be applied in order to show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right)^k}{k!} \to e.$$

Now consider the sequence
$$z_n := \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^k}{k!}.$$

Since $z_n$ is dominated by $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$ it follows that $z_n$ converges to some $0 \leq c \leq e$.
I have shown by direct algebraic manipulations that $z_n \to e$.
Can the above theorem be also applied here in some way?

There is a double sequence $x_{n,k} := 1 - \frac{k}{n}$ which converges to $1$ for each fixed $k$. When setting $g_k(x) := \frac{x^k}{k!}$ then $z_n = \sum_{k=0}^n g_k(x_{n,k})$.

More generally, can the above theorem be appropriately generalized (e.g. $f$ is analytic and $f_n$ the first $n$ terms of the power series of $f$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Given $ε \in (0,1)$:
$\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}$

As $n \to \infty$:

Let $m = \lfloor εn \rfloor$.

Given $k \in \nn_{\le m}$:

$(1-ε)^k \le (1-\frac{k}{n})^k$.

Therefore $\displaystyle e(1-ε) - ε \le e^{1-ε} - \frac{1}{m!} \le \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(1-ε)^k}{k!} \le \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(1-\frac{k}{n})^k}{k!} \le \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} = e$.

[because $1-ε \le e^{-ε}$ and $-ε \le \dfrac{1}{m!}$ since $n \to \infty$.]

Therefore $\displaystyle e - (e+1)ε \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(1-\frac{k}{n})^k}{k!} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(1-\frac{k}{n})^k}{k!} \le e$

Therefore $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(1-\frac{k}{n})^k}{k!} = e$.

**Notes**

Notice that I used limit inferior/superior above because we do not know the existence of the limit. This technique is extremely elementary but very powerful and can be used in almost all such limits, including those that involve limits of integrals. Other people often use things like the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but unless in completely abstract settings that is an unnecessarily heavy hammer. Also, in some cases it is troublesome to have to manipulate into a form on which the theorems work.

Comment: I know I haven't really answered your questions of whether we can use the theorem for uniformly convergent function sequences, but what I present here is a typically untaught and underestimated method that should be considered first before resorting to the general but weaker theorems.

Comment: Nice idea for a lower bound in the sandwich. However, I do not quite understand why $e^{1-\varepsilon}-1/m! \leq \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(1-\varepsilon)^k}{k!}$, i.e. $\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{(1-\varepsilon)^k}{k!} \leq \frac{1}{m!}$ and then you let your upper bound $m$ in the summation increase to the much larger $n$.

Comment: @yadaddy: I threw away positive terms and decreased the rest, so the inequality holds.

Comment: Your $\varepsilon$ is fixed in order to create some room. The value $n$ is also fixed before taking the limit $n \to \infty$.The problem appears when $m = 0$. Take as an example $n=10$ and $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{20}$. Then $m = 0$, $e^{1-\varepsilon} - \frac{1}{m!} \approx 1.58571$ and $\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(1-\varepsilon)^k}{k!} = 1$.

Comment: @yadaddy: Your comment shows that you don't understand the technique I used. $n \to \infty$ does not mean **you** can choose any $n$ you like. It means that (for any $ε$ you choose) **I** can choose some suitable bound for $n$ such that no matter what larger $n$ you choose what I claim under $n \to \infty$ holds. So you cannot require me to choose $n = 10$ for $ε = \frac{1}{20}$.

Comment: @yadaddy: Of course you could give a bound on the tail of the power series that works for all $m$ but I was too lazy.

Comment: Ok, so when I understood you right, I just restate your technique in quantifiers. For all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$ we have $\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{(1-\varepsilon)^k}{k!} \leq \frac{1}{m!}$ where $m := \lfloor \varepsilon n \rfloor$. In particular, in this way we can get rid of the possibility to have $m = 0$ (for which such an inequality does not hold in general).

Comment: @yadaddy: Correct, and don't forget to choose $n_0$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{m!} \le ε$ as well. It is very good that you want to restate it in quantifiers, but after a while of using this kind of technique you will find that often it is cleaner to work forward and not to perform the backward reasoning to obtain the explicit bounds. For example, it is convenient to be able to say that as $x \to \infty$, we have $x > 10$.

Comment: Thank you! I will wait some more time (until marking the question as solved) for the possibility that someone else does know how to apply the uniform convergence technique in some way.

Comment: @yadaddy: By the way, you may notice that your sequence is monotonic and upper bounded and hence convergent. If you want you can use this to fact to avoid using $\liminf$ and $\limsup$. However, you should try to find a similar limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(1+\frac{k}{n})^k}{k!}$, which is not (obviously) monotonic but the above approach works perfectly.